# How to display the status of an AppVeyor build on a Branch or PR in GitHub?

Tags: appveyor

We are soon to move from Bitbucket to GitHub. At present we have good integration with AppVeyor and Bitbucket for the status of our builds on branches and PRs.

I cant find any documentation on how to get this same level of integration with GitHub.  We have connected GitHub to AppVeyor using the GitHub App.

Multiple status badges for all the branches in the ReadMe is not a good option for us.

Does anyone have any documentation or links that would help?